# What are the known or used numerical methods for integration over the sphere $S^2$ ? and what about over $S^3$?

Tags: numerics, integration

What are the numerical methods available to compute integrals over $S^2$, for the particular integration :
$$\int_{S^2} f(\omega)\,d\sigma(\omega)\ , \quad \text{ where $d\sigma$ is the usual measure on the sphere }S^2 $$
And $\omega= (\theta, \phi)$ is a direction (or a unit vector) given by a point on this sphere.

I am guessing an algorithm can proceed by computing Riemann sums as the usual single variable integration? Then maybe a trapezoidal approximation is used?

Any idea on how to implement this on Matlab or Mathematica ?

Comment: Have you done a literature search for "integration over the sphere" or similar? There are clever algorithms for choosing quadrature points spaced in specific ways on the surface of the sphere.

Comment: I have done some literature search, I ask here as well to make sure, do you have a particular paper in mind about those quadrature points?

Comment: No, but I know that the ACM Transactions on Mathematical Software (ACM TOMS) has published such papers in the past. It might be worth looking through its index. (Full disclosure: I am the editor-in-chief of ACM TOMS.)

Comment: For S² there is the R package **SphericalCubature**.